# Creating multiple model objects if they do not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Models:
Store - id, name
Source - id, name
User - id, name
StoreUser - store_id, user_id
StoreSourceDeduction - store_id, source_id
StoreSourceRevenue - store_id, source_id
Transaction - store_id, source_id, deduction:boolean, user_id, amount, submitted_at, created_at, updated_at

(StoreSource split into Deduction and Revenue to make use of the Nested Form Fields gem)

I have routes set up as such: /transactions/:store_id/:date

When navigating to /transactions/1/08112017, if there are no records in the Transaction model for that date, I need to create a row in the Transaction table for each of the StoreSourceDeduction and StoreSourceRevenue models for store 1 and display a form for each record's amount field.

From the Transaction controller, how do I create multiple new Transaction objects while automatically populating the store_id, user_id, deduction, source_id fields, and how do I recall them to allow edits?

**EDIT**

I believe I solved the creation of objects:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_transactions, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_store, only: [:store]
  before_action :get_sources, only: [:show]
  before_action :check_date, only: [:show]

  # GET /transactions
  # GET /transactions.json
  def index
    @transactions = Transaction.all
  end

  def store
  end

  # GET /transactions/1
  # GET /transactions/1.json
  def show
    if is_today?
      if @transactions.count == 0
        @deductions.each do |d|
          row = Transaction.new(:store_id => params[:store_id],
                                :source_id => d.source_id,
                                :user_id => current_user.id,
                                :deduction => true)
          row.save
        end

        @revenues.each do |r|
          row = Transaction.new(:store_id => params[:store_id],
                                :source_id => r.source_id,
                                :user_id => current_user.id,
                                :deduction => false)
          row.save
        end

      end
    end
  end

  # GET /transactions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /transactions
  # POST /transactions.json
  def create

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /transactions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /transactions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @transaction.update(transaction_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @transaction, notice: 'Transaction was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @transaction }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /transactions/1
  # DELETE /transactions/1.json
  def destroy
    @transaction.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to transactions_url, notice: 'Transaction was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_transactions
      @transactions = Transaction.where("store_id = :store_id AND date = :date",
                                        {store_id: params[:store_id], date: params[:transaction_date]})
    end

    def set_store
      @transactions = Transaction.where("store_id = :store_id",
                                        {store_id: params[:store_id]})
    end

    def is_today?
      date = params[:transaction_date]
      today = Date.today().strftime('%m%d%Y')
      date == today
    end

    def check_date
      @date = Transaction.where("date = :date", {date: params[:date]})
    end

    def get_sources
      @deductions = StoreSourceDeduction.where("store_id = :store_id", {store_id: params[:store_id]})
      @revenues = StoreSourceRevenue.where("store_id = :store_id", {store_id: params[:store_id]})
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def transaction_params
      params.require(:transaction).permit(:store_id, :user_id, :source_id, :amount, :submitted_at)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Edited with my progress, though I'm confused as to why "if is_today?" isn't running the code..

Comment: "Isn't running the code" meaning what? Unrelated, but `return true if (date == today)` can be shortened to `date == today`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still pretty green. Meaning that it should be true but the code block isn't being run as if it were. I've tested the code in console and it works.

Comment: Scratch that, issue with params. Oops.